# Refactoring variables and function names in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, refactoring

In eclipse you can refactor all variables and function names by hitting CTRL+SHIFT+R which is great. I am editing someone else's matlab script and would like to change a lot of their varaibles and I was wondering if there is something similar in matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab editor in 2012a allows you to press `shift + enter` to change all of the common variables in a script or function when you start editing one of them.

Otherwise I would suggest find and replace.

Comment: And when it doesn't work when the variable is not initialized (or assigned) within the file/scope, a temporary dummy pre-allocation allows it.